# MySQL DB driven menu generator function

Tags: php, mysql, function, recursion, navigation

Recently I've written recursive PHP function which generates website navigation based on parent-child structure like this

```
<ul>
  <li>parent
     <li>child</li>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Code looks like that

```
function generateMenu($parent, $level, $db){
  $q = $db->query("select id, name FROM menu WHERE parent = '$parent'");

  if($level > 0 && $q->num_rows > 0) echo "\n<ul>\n";

   while($row=$q->fetch_object()){
      echo "<li>";
      echo '<a href="?page=' .$page. '">' . $row->name . '</a>';
      //display this level's children
      generateMenu($row->id, $level++, $menu, $db);
      echo "</li>\n\n";
    }

    if($level > 0 &&  $q->num_rows > 0) echo "</ul>\n";
}
```

The piece of code above simply echoes `<ul><li>` structure (like given above example) from db table.

**Now the questions is, how to create navigation menu like on this website?**

*Please take a look at left sidebar.*

http://www.smithsdetection.com/continuous_vapour_sampling.php

Now i think that:

1. First of all we need to echo all parents
2. Function must get current pages id as an input value (for ex. $current)
3. Function must echo til' current pages level

I can't figure out how to modify my function, to get output like on given website. PLease help.

**BTW**

My db table looks like that

[image]

*NOTE* Please don't post answers about sql injection holes, I've already taken care about them: checking with in_array (if variable listed in column names array) and passing through real_escape.

Comment: `generateMenu($row->id, $level++, $menu, $db);` should probably be `generateMenu($row->id, $level+1, $menu, $db);`.

Comment: )) http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php

Comment: I am aware of the increment operator, but you are using `$level` after it is incremented, too.  Consider when `$level = 0`: `if($level > 0 && $q->num_rows > 0) echo "\n<ul>\n";` will NOT output an opening `<ul>`, then later `generateMenu($row->id, $level++, $menu, $db);` _increments `$level` to 1_ so that after your while loop, `if($level > 0 &&  $q->num_rows > 0) echo "</ul>\n";` WILL output a closing `</ul>`, _which is not matched to any opening one_.  Check your HTML that gets returned to see.

Comment: Furthermore... if `$level = 0`, when you call `generateMenu($row->id, $level++, $menu, $db)` `$level` actually gets incremented _after_ you pass it to the function, so the function _always_ sees `$level = 0`.  Compare: `$level++` with `++$level`, and _read the manual link you posted above_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the current page id is in the var `$current` and that $db is an open MySQLi DB connection:

```
// first get your current page's path back to root:
// $stack will be a stack of menus to show
$stack = array();

// always expand current menu:
$stack[] = $current;

// now starting at $current, we go through the `menu` table adding each parent
// menu id to the $stack until we get to 0:
$i = $current;
while ( $i > 0 ) {
  // get parent of $i
  $query = sprintf('SELECT `parent` FROM `menu` WHERE id=%d LIMIT 1', $i);
  $result = $db->query($query);

  if (!$result) {
    // do error handling here
  }

  $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

  // save parent id into $i...
  $i = $row['parent'];

  // ...and push it onto $stack:
  $stack[] = $i;
}

/**
 * @param int $parent the parent ID of the menu to draw.
 * @param array $stack the stack of ids that need to be expanded
 * @param string $indent string for pretty-printing html
 * @param MySQLi $db Open db connection
 */
function generateMenu($parent, $stack, $indent, $db){

  // $next is the next menu id that needs expanding
  $next = array_pop($stack);

  $query = sprintf('SELECT `id`, `name` FROM `menu` WHERE `parent`=%d', $parent);

  $result = $db->query($query);

  if ( ! $result ) {
    // do error handling here
  }

  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "\n$indent<ul>\n";

    while($row = $result->fetch_object()){
      echo "$indent  <li>\n";
      echo "$indent    <a href=\"?page={$row->id}\">{$row->name}</a>\n";

      //display this level's children, if it's the $next menu to need to be drawn:
      if ($row->id == $next)
        generateMenu($next, $stack, "$indent    ", $db);

      echo "$indent  </li>\n\n";
    }
    echo "$indent</ul>\n";
  }
  $result->free();
}

$first = array_pop($stack); // should always be 0
generateMenu($first, $stack, '', $db);
```

Comment: I don't understand this part `$stack[] = $current;

$i = $current;` $current is the current pages id as we declared above right?

Comment: Yes. We need to add `$current` to the stack of menus to display. `$stack[] = $current;` does that. We are then using `$i` to travel backwards through the DB finding all ancestors of `$current`.  The first ancestor we are looking for is the parent of `$current`, so we set `$i = $current` then in the while loop we execute a query to find the parent id, then change `$i` to = the parent id, then push the parent id onto the stack and if the parent id (i.e., `$i`) is > 0, we do it again.  Looking at your table, if `$current = 12`, then after the while loop, `$stack` = array(12, 10, 4, 0);

Comment: Try following it through, line-by-line, and writing down what each variable is at each line and I'm sure you'll see what happens.

Comment: how to set as active current oage? class=active i mean

Comment: Just add `if ($row->id == $current)` in the while loop.  Do you want to add the class to the `<li>` or or `<a>`?

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at this: http://www.ferdychristant.com/blog/archive/DOMM-7QJPM7

You should try to fetch the whole hierarchy with one query to fix performance issue.

Comment: is my question about performance problems? it's not the answer. please comment it or delete

Comment: than just have a look at the blog post. your question is about hierarchical data, and there is a solution for it.

Comment: @user978733 You're a bundle of joy

Comment: Or (assuming the `menu` table does not get changed too often) index the `parent` column.  That way the difference in approaches will be very small.